# How to set up maven repository on a local windows server to remotely access using pom.xml

Tags: maven, networking, repository

I have a windows server running with maven installed, I need to create an environment where if an artefact is not found on my local repository maven will search the server repository which is in an internal network, and if its not found there to look at the central repository.

And once found the artefact would be downloaded to both the local and networked repositories.

Comment: Check out Artifactory (http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview)

Comment: Or use [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) is simpler to install.

Comment: Is there a way to set up a repository without a third party tool, and just using the file system? I work in a big organization and everything must be approved for use, so the least tools I have to ask for, the better it will be.